# User login failed for <user> in production but same connection string works from local client

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-sql-database, asp.net-core-3.1, azure-sql-server

I have an Azure database setup of which I have included the below connection string as I believe it should be. Problem is when I try to run my client app in production, the server returns a 500 internal error. After investigating it through remote debugging I find that it's saying

```
"Login failed for user "<my user_id>"
```

My Appsettings.json
[image]

My connection string provided during runtime when deploying my api
[image]

Don't worry about the blacked-out portions... I've verified those to be the same in both.

Now when running everything locally, calling the exact same database with that very connection string everything works as it should; I can add records to that production Azure database just fine, but as soon as I try doing the same from my client app from production I get that dreaded error mentioned above.

Can anyone tell me what might be happening? I've been over and over this and it's driving me mad. I've even gone as far as changing the connection string to be Server=... I've made sure to append the @ to the user_id. I believe I've tried just about everything I could find that wasn't 8 years old, including searching similar issues here... nothing seems to be quite like my issue exactly.

If you need more information let me know and I'll update my question.

Thanks!

EDIT: Adding this to show I've already added all of my output IPs from my api app service to my Sql server firewall. Can someone tell me if all my settings look good?

[image]

Comment: Azure SQL databases have firewalls enabled. Have you whitelisted your API wherever that is deployed?

Comment: @A_kat You know... I didn't think about that, I'll look into it.

Comment: @A_kat Nope... added all my apis app's outbound IPs and no dice. Still the same problem. Could it take time to propagate maybe?

Comment: For me it was almost instant in my cases. Did you try to redeploy your app as well?

Comment: @A_kat I did... though I may try that again.

Comment: where's the app deployed? Azure?  If so also check the option "Allow Azure services and resources to access this server" option is Yes.   That's in the firewalls settings as well.

Comment: @TimMylott Yeah, that was selected by default. It's checked.

Comment: @TimMylott I added another photo of my firewall settings, can you have a look?

Comment: I found you have used the specific user to login in the Azure sql server. I suggest you could re-check the user has added well into it. Details, you could refer to this [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/adding-users-to-your-sql-azure-database/).

Comment: @BrandoZhang Thanks, but I am the administrator of this db so I'm using my user_id and password. What's odd to me, and obviously the Azure engineers I spoke with today is that I can login in SQLMS, I can add records only when I'm running the API from localhost, but not while in production. I'll update if we figure this out.